# Not registered handle cms_page_listing_data_source

Tags: magento-2.1

i am getting

> "Not registered handle cms_page_listing_data_source "

When i load my `cms/page/index` **controller**

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem with merging **app/code/Namespace/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml** file in **app/code/Namespace/Module/etc/di.xml** and removing **app/code/Namespace/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml** file.

In my case, it was Doofinder_Feed module that causing this issue.
But it can happen form any module that have both  **app/code/Namespace/Module/etc/adminhtml/di.xml** and **app/code/Namespace/Module/etc/di.xml** files.